# PHP: "Array to string conversion" error when variable is a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array from Amazon's API, which I'm iterating. When I try to echo or print() one of the values I get an "Array to string conversion" error.

The value in question **is a string**, which I've confirmed with var_dump().

Is this a bug in PHP v.5.5.8(-1~dotdeb.1) or am I going crazy?

This is the line of code that causes the hangup (using Blade, but this is the produced PHP):

`<td><a href='http://<?php echo $instance['PublicDnsName']; ?>' target='_blank'><?php echo $instance['PublicDnsName']; ?></a></td>`

I'm on Ubuntu Server via Vagrant, under Windows 7 as host OS.

EDIT: If I print_r() the value, it works fine, **but** it appends a "1" to the output.

EDIT2: It seems to be an issue with Blade, perhaps, as I can echo the value normally within my controller class instead of in the view/template. I'm using Laravel 4 and its Blade templating engine.

EDIT3:
Here is the relevant portion of my Blade template:
`<td><a href='{{ $instance['PublicDnsName'] }}' target='_blank'>{{ $instance['PublicDnsName'] }}</a></td>`

This is inside a nested foreach loop.

The big data array comes from Amazon's EC2, thusly:

`$data = $this->ec2->DescribeInstances()->getAll();`
As mentioned earlier, if I print this out within the controller, it will print the string correctly without errors.

I also tried it with normal PHP tags, without the Blade specific syntax, but it yields the same result.

Comment: try a print_r($var) so if it's an array really you could see the output as of an array, if not put your var_dump() here

Comment: Could you also show code, how do you var_dump etc. and results including full error messages and rendered html? Description is usually just not enough. A phpfiddle could be helpful too.

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($instance['PublicDnsName']); echo '</pre>';`

...prints: `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

`echo '<pre>'; var_dump($instance['PublicDnsName']); echo '</pre>';`

...prints: `string(50) "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"`

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark... Have you tried doing this outside of blade? I.e into a normal php file, I'm not familiar with blade but could it be causing the problem?

Comment: jd181: No, but I seem to be able to echo it out within the controller, so Blade could have something to do with it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question with the blade template code, and the code where the variable is assigned to the template if possible?

Comment: Added third edit to the question.

Comment: Have you tried a var_dump(); in the actual template to check if the type has been altered by blade or something?

Comment: Yes I have.
This: `<pre>{{ var_dump($instance['PublicDnsName']) }}</pre>`

...results in this: `string(50) "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"`

Comment: It really is a string and not an array. I don't get it.
Trying this: `$PublicDnsName_string = end($instance['PublicDnsName']) . '....';` gives the obvious error: "end() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given". I'm losing my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: I'm an idiot. The AWS API returns both a string **OR** an array with just the value 1. So, no bug anywhere. Thanks for the help!